# i there a way to rewrite the code?,i can not seem to get it right, i can not seem to get the input correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to edit the code i previously wrote to make it work with a input, I will attach the problem. I can not seem to get it to work.
it has to be some sort of input,

```
string =" "

reversed_string = string[::-1]

result_string = " ".join(string)

for a in range (0 ,3):
   result_string += chr(ord('a')+a)

for a in range(0 , 2)[::-1]:
   result_string += chr(ord('a')+a)

print result_string
```

[image]

Comment: put lots of print() and you will see the problem on your code. This is your assignment so own it. It is more fun to find and fix the issue.

Comment: There are a number of ways to read keyboard input, please follow your previous coursework around reading input, and set your string variable with the result of a keyboard input read. This is a common pattern in general programming courses, please post your attempt if it doesn't work, or post your own answer to this question if you can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

string =" "

## add this to input from keyboard

```
input( 'type a letter from a to z')
```

Comment: String = input('type a letter from a to z')

Comment: forgot to add the string =

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest I could make the answer

```
character = 97
char_list = []
con = True
a = 0
for interger in range(26):
    char = chr(character)
    char_list.append(char)
    character = character+1
get_char = input("Enter a letter from a-z")
while con == True:
    if get_char == char_list[a]:
        b = char_list[:a+1]
        char_list.reverse()
        print(b+char_list[-a:])
        con = False
    else:
        a = a+1
```

Comment: I could have made the char_list as the alphabet but doing it individually is annoying af